# Un-merge a dataframe based on a column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am reading a csv file into a pandas dataframe and the data inside dataframe is as below:

```
    item        seq_no      db_xml
0   28799179    5       ['<my_xml>....</my_xml>']
1   28839888    1       ['<my_xml>....</my_xml>']
2   28840113    75      ['<my_xml>....</my_xml>']
3   28852466    20,22   ['<my_xml1>....</my_xml1>', '<my_xml2>....</my_xml2>']
```

I need to convert above dataframe as below i.e. each `seq_no` for same `item` and its `db_xml` should be in different rows. I need to unmerge `seq_no` of same `item` in subsequent rows.

```
    item        seq_no      db_xml
0   28799179    5       ['<my_xml>....</my_xml>']
1   28839888    1       ['<my_xml>....</my_xml>']
2   28840113    75      ['<my_xml>....</my_xml>']
3   28852466    20      ['<my_xml1>....</my_xml1>']
4   28852466    22      ['<my_xml2>....</my_xml2>']
```

Please let me know on how to achieve the same in pandas so that even `seq_no` is also split and in separate rows?

Comment: Do you need `df = df.explode('db_xml')` ?

Comment: @jezrael: Thanks it works for the column db_xml but seq_no is set to 20,22 in both columns. How can I set it to 20 for first column and 22 for second column?

Comment: I see it, you can create list in `seq_no` column by `df.seq_no = df.seq_no.str.split(',')` and then use solution form linked second dupe answer.